# How can I make Rythmbox (or Banshee) scan a specific directory for .is_audio_player

Tags: networking, 14.04, software-recommendation, rhythmbox, music

I would like to configure (or cheat) Rhythmbox to treat an arbitrary directory (network share), so that I can automatically use it to send my music there (and convert it to suitable formats using .is_audio_player), as opposed to using external tools.

Specifically, I want to transfer music to my Windows Phone, but apparently transferring music normally to the SD card leads to a world of problems (duplicate and more song entries -> using up loads of memory and unbearably slowing the phone). Unfortunately, the native program doesn't convert on the fly,ando I was hoping to use Rhythmbox to pick and transcode what songs I want and then use the native app to transfer what I choose to the phone. I could work around it by simply using some removable drive (which is a hassle if I intend to transfer the music often) or an external app (which is a hassle because I like to pick songs as I listen to them), but I wonder if there is some better solution.)

Comment: Is your phone not recognized by Rhythm Box (or Banshee)? could you add the content of .is_audio_player to your question? Is this helpful: http://almost-a-technocrat.blogspot.com/2010/11/isaudioplayer.html#.U8kj8lEYaRs ?

Comment: I am facing the same question. Did you find a solution in the meantime?

Comment: @mo': No, I'm afraid not. I've given up.

Answer (score 0):

A) If you want to use any directory (network share) in Rythmbox

1) Open rythmbox

2) Click Edit, then Preferences

You will see something similar to this:

[image: rythmboxprefs]

3) Click Browse, choose the location that your network share is mounted.

4) Make sure watch my library for new files is checked (as shown).

B) Based on our chat, I believe that you have manged to use a pendrive with .is_audio_player. Edit that file and copy it to the root of your device. You will want to edit it to comply with the format discussed below. If you have a media player that requires a is_audio_player file, this means that it is not automatically recognized by Ubuntu and it is a bug (ie your drive does not appear in the list Readers automatically detected). So that other users like you are not obliged to define such a file and your drive is automatically recognized in future versions of Ubuntu, please report the bug by running the command: ubuntu-bug media-player-info.

**is_audio_player** format

Here is a practical example of properties that you can add to this file .is_audio_player (each is explained in more detail below).

For a complete list of all available properties, refer to the [HAL standard](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?depth=1&hl=en&prev=/search%3Fq%3D.is_audio_player%26client%3Dubuntu%26hs%3D8v7%26channel%3Dfs&rurl=translate.google.com&sl=fr&u=http://www.marcuscom.com/hal-spec/hal-spec.html&usg=ALkJrhiQAVS9F7Blmlgz4YweHn9UzR3g4Q#device-properties-portable_audio_player)

audio_folders = Music /, Other folder / subfolder
 folder_depth = 8
 output_formats = audio / mpeg, application / ogg, audio / x-ms-wma
 input_formats = audio / mpeg

Parameter "audio_folders"

List all folders that contain music. Other files will be ignored. \ \ The order is important because the music will transfer to the first folder in the list.

In the absence of this parameter, the music is sought throughout the volume and transfers are to the root.
Parameter "folder_depth"

Specifies the number of child folders in which music files can be found:

```
This parameter is relative to the folder containing music, as specified in <audio_folders>;
All audio files located in another child folder will not be seen;
The value 0 indicates that there is no depth limit subfolders.
```

Examples:

```
If the player stores all the music with the tree / <audio_folders> / <Artiste> / <Album>, use the folder_depth parameter = 2;
For a compilation of Beatles containing two discs with the tree / <audio_folders> / Beatles/Compilation/Disque1 with the folder_depth parameter = 2, audio files located in Disk1 will not be seen.
```

This parameter is also used when importing new songs:

```
folder_depth = 0 places the files in the root folder specified in the first audio_folders as
<audio_folders> / <artiste> - <album> - <PDISKID> piste> - name> morceau>;
folder_depth = 1: Place the files in a subfolder. This will be placed in the first indicated in the form audio_folders
<audio_folders> / <artiste> - <album> / <PDISKID> piste> - name> morceau>;
folder_depth = 2 and more: places the files in two subfolders. These will be placed in the first audio_folders indicated in the form
<audio_folders> / <artiste> / <album> / <PDISKID> piste> - name> morceau>.
```

In the absence of parameters, folder_depth = 0 is used by default.
Parameter "output_formats"

Indicates the formats supported by the player in mime type. The first type is indicated that used for the automatic conversion when importing new songs.

Mime types most commonly used:

```
audio / mpeg (mp3)
application / ogg (ogg)
audio / x-ms-wma (wma).
```

In the absence of this parameter, the software used for the import will use the format specified in preferences.
Parameter "input_formats"

Indicates formats that can record player with microphone or from a radio.

Mime types most commonly used:

```
audio / mpeg (mp3)
application / ogg (ogg)
audio / x-ms-wma (wma).
```

In the absence of this parameter, it is considered that the player can not record audio.

Source (B):http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=fr&u=http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/is_audio_player&prev=/search%3Fq%3D.is_audio_player%26client%3Dubuntu%26hs%3D8v7%26channel%3Dfs

Comment: And *how* will that allow me to do any of the things I asked about?

Comment: Did you try it? What didn't it do that you expected? Please help us help you by clarifying. I was under the impression that you wanted to set Rythmbox up using a network share that you could transfer your music to and have it converted to the format of your choice. If this is not what you intend, [edit] [1] [1:] http://askubuntu.com/posts/498210/edit your question to make clear what you intend. Thank you.

Comment: If I do that, I will add that directory as music location. But how will I then transfer files there and convert them as per .is_audio_player? I think I've made myself pretty clear, and it seems to me like what you propose is quite the opposite of what I asked about.

Comment: You still do not understand (or I don't). I don't want to add more files to my music library, I want to *transfer my files* to a specific directory. It's not about a media player that is nor automatically recognized: I'm talking about using .is_audio_player to make rhythmbox *think* something is an audio player that supports such and such formats and convert files on the fly as it transfers them over there. My problem is, how to make rhythmbox recognize a random directory or network share as if it was a mounted drive.

Comment: without mounting it?

Comment: I don't care. If you tell me how to mount an arbitrary directory on my computer/subdirectory of network share (or make rhythmbox think I did), it'd be just as well. (Actually, rhythmbox seems to have serious problems with mp3 encoding, so I'm not sure if I'll need it anyhow...)

Comment: It appears that I don't understand. Rhythmbox can support encoding to MP3 as far as I can tell. (not my preferred format, but): http://imgur.com/QxGECTh Have you installed ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Comment: That was a side remark, unrelated to the issue at hand. That said, I have them installed, and still RB complains that it has to download codecs and can't find any. Again, not what the question is about. What it is about is how to make RB scan arbitrary directory for .is_audio_player/consider it as an external audio player (like I can do with a pendrive if I add the file).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15824/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-tomasz).

Comment: Expanded on answer.